# Dell 2.5" SAS Disk Caddy Compatibility

Tags: dell, hard-drive, sas

Does anyone know if the 2.5" SAS Dell Hotswap caddys from the new R610's are compatible with those from the 1950's.

They are listed as seperate part numbers, but I am unsure if they are physically compatible and dell just spin the line of "buy the specific ones".

Answer (score 4):

You want to put a 1950's hard drive into your Dell??? That thing will never fit in!! They used to have to use a fork lift!

[image: 1950's IBM hard drive]

Well technically it's a 1960's hard drive.

Comment: Humor at Serverfault? 
Good that at least one posting managed to escape the Delete Nazis.

Answer (score 3):

They might look different but thats about it. I just swapped drives from the two machines and installed fine.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have any R610, but the caddies for the R710 are very different from the ones for the 1950/2950

Comment: I was going to say the exact same thing.  I have some R610s, but I don't have any 1950s with 2.5" drives.  I suspect they are not compatible.

Answer (score 0):

The 1950 and the R's are different generation servers, there might be quite a difference, but I might be mistaken.